# When to use Spring @ConfigurationCondition vs. @Condition?

Tags: java, spring

Spring 4 has two new annotations `@Condition` and `@ConfigurationConditon` for controlling whether a bean is added to the spring application context. The JavaDoc does not provide enough context / big picture to understand the use cases for `@ConfigurationCondition`.

When should `@ConfigurationCondition` be used vs. `@Condition`?

```
public interface ConfigurationCondition extends Condition {

    /**
     * Returns the {@link ConfigurationPhase} in which the condition should be evaluated.
     */
    ConfigurationPhase getConfigurationPhase();

    /**
     * The various configuration phases where the condition could be evaluated.
     */
    public static enum ConfigurationPhase {

        /**
         * The {@link Condition} should be evaluated as a {@code @Configuration} class is
         * being parsed.
         *
         * <p>If the condition does not match at this point the {@code @Configuration}
         * class will not be added.
         */
        PARSE_CONFIGURATION,

        /**
         * The {@link Condition} should be evaluated when adding a regular (non
         * {@code @Configuration}) bean. The condition will not prevent
         * {@code @Configuration} classes from being added.
         *
         * <p>At the time that the condition is evaluated all {@code @Configuration}s
         * will have been parsed.
         */
        REGISTER_BEAN
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

[`ConfigurationCondition`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationCondition.html) is a specialization of `Condition` for `@Configuration` classes.

Plain `Condition` is just fine for 99% of your use cases so you should consider that first. The specialization is really about determining in which **phase** of the processing of `@Configuration` classes the condition should be evaluated.

There are two phases:

- `PARSE_CONFIGURATION` evaluates the condition when the `@Configuration`-annotated class is parsed. This gives a chance to fully exclude the configuration class
- `REGISTER_BEAN` evaluates the condition when a bean from a configuration class is registered. This does not prevent the configuration class to be added but it allows to skip a bean definition if the condition does not match (as defined by the `matches` method of the `Condition` interface)

Spring Boot has a `OnBeanCondition` that basically checks during the registration phase if another bean is present. This is the core of `ConditionalOnBean` that basically does something when a bean is present

Answer (score 3):

There are no `@ConfigurationCondition` or `@Condition` annotations, but `@Conditional` only. For `@Conditional` one can specify a `Condition` or a `ConfigurationCondition`.

`@Conditional` determines if a `@Configuration` class is to be enabled or disabled based on a condition. As the [documentation says](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-conditional) the best example is the `@Profile` annotation itself, which determines which beans are loaded or not based on the chosen profiles.

The two phases which are considered by `ConfigurationCondition` are the ones that a `@Configuration` class goes through: first the class is parsed and then the beans are registered and created.

Comment: emphasis on a "Condition OR a ConfigurationCondition"