# How get working @Value or Environment in a class implementing the Condition/ConfigurationCondition interfaces

Tags: spring, spring-3, spring-java-config, spring-4

I am working with only JavaConfig.

I have the following declaration:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

it is mandatory for JavaConfig according with the following post:
[Spring 3.2 @value annotation with pure java configuration does not work, but Environment.getProperty works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097521/spring-3-2-value-annotation-with-pure-java-configuration-does-not-work-but-env)

The following code works perfect (many @Values by testing purposes):

```
@Configuration
public class ActiveMQServerConfiguration {

    @Value("${localhost.address}")
    private String localHost;

    @Value("${remotehost.address}")
    private String remoteHost;

    @Value("${localhost.port}")
    private Integer localPort;

    @Value("${remotehost.port}")
    private Integer remotePort;

    @Bean(name="connectionFactory")
    @Conditional(LocalHostStatusCondition.class)
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory localConnectionFactory(
            @Value("${localhost.protocol}") String protocol,
            @Value("${localhost.address}") String host,
            @Value("${localhost.port}") String port ){

        System.out.println("protocol: "+protocol);
        System.out.println("host: "+host);
        System.out.println("port: "+port);

        System.out.println("localHost: "+localHost);
        System.out.println("localPort: "+localPort);
        System.out.println("remoteHost: "+remoteHost);
        System.out.println("remotePort: "+remotePort);
```

I can see in the console/terminal

**Alpha**

```
protocol: tcp
host: 127.0.0.1
port: 61616
localHost: 127.0.0.1
localPort: 61616
remoteHost: 192.168.1.34
remotePort: 61616
```

But the following does not works how expected:

```
public class LocalHostStatusCondition implements Condition {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LocalHostStatusCondition.class);

    @Value("${localhost.address}")
    private String localHost;

    @Value("${remotehost.address}")
    private String remoteHost;

    @Value("${localhost.port}")
    private Integer localPort;

    @Value("${remotehost.port}")
    private Integer remotePort;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        logger.info("LocalHostStatusCondition...");

        System.out.println("localHost: "+localHost);
        System.out.println("localPort: "+localPort);
        System.out.println("remoteHost: "+remoteHost);
        System.out.println("remotePort: "+remotePort);
        System.out.println("Env..." + environment.getProperty("localhost.address", String.class) );
```

Practically the same and even working with **Environment**

The output is:

**Beta**

```
localHost: null
localPort: null
remoteHost: null
remotePort: null
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.manuel.jordan.infrastructure.support.LocalHostStatusCondition.matches(LocalHostStatusCondition.java:42)
```

According with the [Condition API](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition.html):

> Conditions must follow the same restrictions as BeanFactoryPostProcessor and take care to never interact with bean instances. For more fine-grained control of conditions that interact with @Configuration beans consider the **ConfigurationCondition** interface.

About **ConfigurationCondition** I have read this [When to use Spring @ConfigurationCondition vs. @Condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299273/when-to-use-spring-configurationcondition-vs-condition) too

I have edited to the following:

```
public class LocalHostStatusCondition implements ConfigurationCondition {

…

    @Override
    public ConfigurationPhase getConfigurationPhase() {
        return ConfigurationPhase.PARSE_CONFIGURATION;
    }
```

If I use:

- **ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN** I get the same output how **Beta**
- **ConfigurationPhase.PARSE_CONFIGURATION;** I get no errors but...

but the console/terminal does not show nothing about the sentences working, I mean, System.out are not printing (I don't understand about this weird behaviour).

How I can resolve this?

> I need have working @Value or Environment, it with the purpose to let know the application if should connect to a local or remote ActiveMQ server.

And yes, I have read the following:
[How do I delay evaluation of a Spring @Conditional configuration annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526643/how-do-i-delay-evaluation-of-a-spring-conditional-configuration-annotation)
seems there is no solution…

Thank You

Comment: I am a bit confused by your usage of `Condition`. Shouldn't your `LocalHostStatusCondition.matches()` evaluates some sort of conditional statement to return a boolean value to determine whether your `ActiveMQServerConfiguration` configuration bean will be registered? Why does your `LocalHostStatusCondition` class needs all these connection properties?

Comment: Regardless, if you are reading these properties from a properties file, have you tried adding `@PropertySource("classpath:youfile.properties")` to your `LocalHostStatusCondition` class?

Comment: @isim , yes, `LocalHostStatusCondition.matches()` returns a boolean value. I am using `LocalHostStatusCondition` to test two server connections, one local and other remote, that's why I need that host/port. If remote exists it is used instead of the local.

Comment: @isim, even if I include `@PropertySource("classpath:youfile.properties")` in the `LocalHostStatusCondition` class based with `Condition/ConfigurationCondition` it fails...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have

```
@Conditional(LocalHostStatusCondition.class)
```

Spring takes the `Class` type you've specified and instantiates it to use its `matches` method. It doesn't consider the instance as a bean, it doesn't perform autowiring on it, nor any `@Value` processing. The latter are true for `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` as well.

You can retrieve the `Environment` from the `ConditionContext` if you want to. The alternative is to load the properties yourself.