# How to silently cancel bean creation?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

```
@Component
public class MyBean {

  @Autowired
  public MyBean(@Value("${optional:#{null}}") String optional) {
    if (optional == null) {
      // cancel bean creation?
    }
  }

}
```

How to silently cancel bean creation? I could throw a `RuntimeException`, but I don't want this cancellation to be considered as an error: the bean must just not be created, the application initialization must go on.

Comment: What's the reason behind this approach?

Comment: @commit `MyBean` is an optional bean that belongs to a framework. Integrating projects may or may not need it. I'm just trying not to pollute the Spring context with unnecessary beans.

Comment: Let me move it to answer that's something that may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can make use of [@Conditional](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html)

**Step 1**- Implement [Condition.matches](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition.html#matches-org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionContext-org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata-) so as to specify when should the bean be created or not.

```
public class SomeCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return System.getProperty("optional") != null;
    }
}
```

*The condition class is referred as direct class (not as spring bean) so it can't use the `@Value` property injection. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25276772/1910582) for alternative*

**Step 2** - In the configuration class specify the above class as *condition* to decide the bean creation

```
@Configuration
public class SomeAppConfig {

    @Bean
    @Condition(SomeCondition.class)
    public MyBean myBean() {
      return new MyBean();
    }
}
```

**P.S.**: I have assumed that you use Java config.

Answer (score 1):

**It's not possible.**

If you don't create a bean you can't use it. It's just a simple Java class and the property used/autowired in the bean are just useless.

However, you may configure profile base configuration beans for different kind of environments like 'Dev', 'Test' or 'Production'.

https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/