# Load Configuration Bean Dynamically

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm making a spring boot app that needs to have basic authentication or Oauth2 depending on a property i have defined.

The problem is that if I created two classes with @configuration the application doesn't start, and if I just leave one and in the configure method I add an if to configure the HttpSecurity object i fails when try to hit the endpoint with basic authentication.

I  try to register bean dynamically this way:

```
@Bean
public ResourceServerSecurityConfig oauthConfig(){
    if(isOauthEnabled){
        return new ResourceServerSecurityConfig();
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
@Bean
public BasicSecurityConfig basicConfig(){
    if(isOauthEnabled){
        return new BasicSecurityConfig ();
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

But the configuration is not loaded. 
Any hints on how this can be archived??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is conditional bean creation. Try using @Conditional.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html

You can create custom conditions based on system properties.

You can also do it with an if but its less readable and will cluster your config but for a short example try this:

```
@Bean
public SecurityConfig basicConfig(@Value("${authentication.type.oauth}" boolean isOauthEnabled)){
    if(isOauthEnabled){
        return new ResourceServerSecurityConfig();
    }else{
        return new BasicSecurityConfig ();
    }
}
```

This is however a dirty hack.

Comment: The "@Conditional" work! well... kind of. It loads the bean depending on a value. The problem I'm having now is that I created a class that implements the Condition interface, but that class is not loading the "@Value" from the properties file. I tried to annotate the class with an "@Component", because for "@value" to work the class should be a bean, but I can't find why the value is not being loaded. Anyway, I marked your answer as the right one, because that solved the original problem ;). Thanks!

Comment: Find the solution to the last problem. Using the ConditionContext from the matches method I was able to read the properties from the file. because as [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276463/how-get-working-value-or-environment-in-a-class-implementing-the-condition-conf) says, 
"Spring takes the Class type you've specified and instantiates it to use its matches method. It doesn't consider the instance as a bean, it doesn't perform autowiring on it, nor any @Value processing. The latter are true for BeanFactoryPostProcessor as well."

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined annotation `@SpringBootApplication` in Spring Boot Application.

Please see sample below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        .......
        }
    }

}
```

Also you can annotate`@Import({ApplicationConfig.class})` to the main application.

Comment: Yes, i already added the @SpringBootApplication annotation to the main application.

Comment: Also you can annotate@Import({ApplicationConfig.class}) to the main application, meaning with the class name of config class

Comment: but i need to load a configuration depending on a property value,  that @import can have a conditional?